# Bottom bar hides the scrollview content

Tags: android, android-layout

Below code has a bottom bar with two buttons which is fixed and not scrollable.

Above bottom bar the layout is scrollable. But the bottom content in the `ScrollView` hides behind the bottom bar.

I tried changing the parent layout which was not fixing the issue.

I don't know where I am wrong. Any help would be really thankfull.

Code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />


    <ScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_full"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:id="@+id/imageall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/price_full_offer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/price_full"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <fone.adipoli.shopping.Rounded_textview
                    android:id="@+id/circle_txt"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="3dp"

                    android:text="" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text="Check Availability"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_available_cart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

                android:text=""
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/enterpin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"

                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/pincheck"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"


                    android:background="#000"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/chnge_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_available"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/change_pin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:text="Change\nPincode"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Description :\n"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/des_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/text_des"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:text="Full details"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addtocart"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"

            android:text="Add to Cart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buynow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"

            android:text="Buy Now "
            android:textColor="@color/white"


            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove whole of the first `LinearLayout`

Add the below line to your `ScrollView`

```
  android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
```

This makes sure that your `ScrollView` ends before the bottom bar so theres no overlapping.

Comment: Thanks.I tried this. But it shows a blank space in the top.

Comment: change the scrollview height to match parent and make sure that scrollview layout below your View. Also your View should be below your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `LinearLayout` add **android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"**
 this will help you
try this

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />


        <ScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_full"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:id="@+id/imageall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/price_full_offer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Price"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/price_full"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <fone.adipoli.shopping.Rounded_textview
                        android:id="@+id/circle_txt"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="3dp"    
                        android:text="" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Check Availability"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_available_cart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/enterpin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                        android:cursorVisible="false"
                        android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/pincheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"


                        android:background="#000"
                        android:text="Check"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/chnge_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_available"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/change_pin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:text="Change\nPincode"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Description :\n"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/des_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/text_des"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Full details"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addtocart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:text="Add to Cart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buynow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:text="Buy Now "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add tag `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"` in your `ScrollView`
It will keep the scrolling above your bottom bar.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_full"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:id="@+id/imageall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/price_full_offer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Price"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/price_full"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <fone.adipoli.shopping.Rounded_textview
                        android:id="@+id/circle_txt"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="3dp"

                        android:text="" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:text="Check Availability"

                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_available_cart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/enterpin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"

                        android:cursorVisible="false"
                        android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/pincheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"


                        android:background="#000"
                        android:text="Check"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/chnge_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_available"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/change_pin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:text="Change\nPincode"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Description :\n"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/des_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/text_des"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:text="Full details"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addtocart"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue"

                    android:text="Add to Cart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buynow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue"

                    android:text="Buy Now "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"


                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />


            <ScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:fillViewport="true">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
               <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="20dp"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_full"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:padding="20dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:scrollbars="none">

                        <LinearLayout

                            android:id="@+id/imageall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/price_full_offer"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Price"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:textColor="#000" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/price_full"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <fone.adipoli.shopping.Rounded_textview
                            android:id="@+id/circle_txt"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"

                            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="3dp"

                            android:text="" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/stock"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                        android:text="Check Availability"

                        android:textAppearance="?             android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_available_cart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/enterpin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"

                            android:cursorVisible="false"
                            android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:padding="5dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/pincheck"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"


                            android:background="#000"
                            android:text="Check"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/chnge_rl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item_available"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/change_pin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                            android:text="Change\nPincode"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Description :\n"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/des_rl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <WebView
                            android:id="@+id/text_des"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"

                            android:text="Full details"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
            android:layout_below:"@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <LinearLayout


                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addtocart"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue"

                    android:text="Add to Cart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buynow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue"

                    android:text="Buy Now "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"


                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove XMLNS from your scrollView, Give an id to scroll view. Then add attribute android:layout_below to the next component which is coming after scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />


<ScrollView    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/scrol_view"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_full"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/imageall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_full_offer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textAppearance="?                               android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_full"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <fone.adipoli.shopping.Rounded_textview
                android:id="@+id/circle_txt"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"

                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="#bcbcbc"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:text="Check Availability"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_available_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enterpin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"

                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pincheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"


                android:background="#000"
                android:text="Check"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/chnge_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_available"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/change_pin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:text="Change\nPincode"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Description :\n"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/des_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/text_des"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:text="Full details"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<LinearLayout


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtocart"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"

        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buynow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"

        android:text="Buy Now "
        android:textColor="@color/white"


        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```